# Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue with rigging and mesh?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

All bones are part of one armature, both arms are one object as well. I did automatic weight thing and the mesh on the right arm acts as it should, but one on the left does that weird thing as you can see. Am i doing something wrong or?

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: can't you keep just what you're showing?

Comment: One sec, i made a file without the unimportant mesh

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=8w6KDDz1" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8w6KDDz1/) here i think this is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist thing, the scale is -1 on the X axis, so apply the scale of your object:

[image]

Once done, you need to check the normals, enable *Face Orientation* in the *Viewport Overlays* panel:

[image]

Blue show face normal orientation, red the opposite, as you can see the normals are flipped outside on the right arm. To recalculate the normals, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Oh i see, how do i exactly recalculate normals if you dont mind explaining, im pretty new to rigging and animationg so im not so sure how to do it since i never had a need for it?

Comment: Never mind, i managed to do it. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Yea i figured it out, thanks for the help man.